# SparkSQL : Is there a "filterPushdown" feature for jdbc datasource

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 2.3, and loading data from MySQL tables.

I would like to know is there is a feature "filterPushdown"  similar to the parquet files.

I have a large table which has millions of rows, of which I need to load portion of data matching certain keys and also timestamp > certian_timestamp.

```
"where key_col in (34,35, .. ) and ts > 1539688500000"
```

After this I need to join this dataset with another small table.

Can I achieve this operations (filtering & join) in the database itself using "filterPushdown" and something like "joinPushdown" ?? (if exists)

Comment: Yes, filters are pushed down to the source database whenever possible.  You can also push down entire query down to database, it has got a special syntax though.  You can read about it at https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html#push-down-a-query-to-the-database-engine

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Filter Pushdown is available for JDBC sources but only for Where Clause.

You can check this at
https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html#push-down-a-query-to-the-database-engine

If for your database it does not work.. Use following to implement it for you.

http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/spark-datasource-v2-part-5/

Hope this helps :)

Cheers!